# É possível integrar o GIT com algum gerenciador de tarefas?

Tags: git, versionamento, trello

Existe alguma forma de integrar algum gerenciador de tarefas (suponhamos, o Trello) onde o desenvolvedor, ao dar um commit em sua atividade, faça a associação do mesmo com alguma tarefa em específico?

Em pesquisas encontrei o Trello com o GitHub, mas mas o objetivo desta trata-se de ferramentas *free* e com repositório privado, onde no caso do GitHub não seria possível.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Com o Redmine funciona esta associação.

Tutoriais de configuração:

- http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Easily_integrate_a_%28SSH_secured%29_GIT_repository_into_redmine
- http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_configure_Redmine_for_advanced_git_integration

Comment: Até então não utilizarei o Redmine, mas achei muito interessante para projetos e equipes maiores. Encontrei o que buscava na utilização de Issues do BitBucket e o GitLab aonde são parecidos.

Answer (score 6):

[O GitHub tem uma lista de ferramentas conhecidas para integração](https://github.com/integrations). Como o GitHub é basicamente um aprimoramento do Git, você pode considerar essas ferramentas como possíveis de serem integradas com qualquer outro sabor do Git.

[Outra ferramenta que sei que integra mas que não está listada aí é o Trac](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_configure_Redmine_for_advanced_git_integration), embora ele seja um gestor de tíquetes, e não necessariamente um organizador de tarefas.

Se a necessidade é integrar com um repositório privado, [sei que o BitBucket integra com o Trac](https://www.cloudpipes.com/integrations/bitbucket/trac). [Aqui tem uma lista (mais abaixo) de todos os serviços possíveis de serem integrados com o BitBucket](https://www.cloudpipes.com/channels/bitbucket).

Comment: Até onde conheço não é possível um repositório privado e free com o GitHub. Minha necessidade atual é um repositório free mas privado. Agradeço pela resposta.

Comment: @anderson Atualizei a resposta. Vou colocar mais alguns links. Vamos ver se te atende.

Answer (score 3):

É possivel realizar uma integraçã entre o JIRA (free para projeto open-source) com o Git, veja links de explicação fornecidos pela propria desenvolvedora: [Link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/JIRA+integration)

É possível gerenciar tarefas no próprio bitbucket (semelhante ao github porem é possível ter um repositório privado de graça) veja o link de explicação fornecido pela própria desenvolvedora: [Link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Use+the+issue+tracker)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o Trello que é otimo + bitbucket que te da repositórios privados free.

Answer (score 1):

É possível integrar também com https://www.visualstudio.com/, que tem Agile Tools, Build, Test, ... é FREE para uma conta de até 5 usuários.